# why this method does not work in excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

> Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057) could not find the specified
>   object.

to shorten the repetition If, I use the code:

```
Sub kodeaktif()
   Dim ni, nu, na As String
   Dim ime As Long
   nu = True
   ni = False
   na = vbNullString
      For Ime = 1 To 20 'jika sumber tidak ada maka terkunci
         Controls("Image" & Ime).Visible = IIf(Sheets("VIP").Cells(34, Ime + 3) <> na, ni, nu)
   Next Ime
End Sub
```

but this code can not be processed in excel vba. anyone know why? give me the alternative

UPDATE. code userform:

```
Private Sub userform_initialize()
       fRef.Caption = "xxxxxxx"
       Sheets("VIP").Select
       Set ws = Sheets("VIP")
         ListBox2.ColumnWidths = "40;0;0;50;0;0;50"
         ListBox2.columnCount = 7
         ListBox2.List = ws.Range("q28:W" & [q300].End(3).Row).Value

        ListBox3.ColumnWidths = "40;0;0;50;0;0;50"
        ListBox3.columnCount = 7
        ListBox3.List = ws.Range("z28:AF" & [z300].End(3).Row).Value
        Call kodeaktif
        End Sub
        Private Sub ListBox2_Click()
        Dim say As Long, a As Byte
        Set ws = Sheets("VIP")
        Label8 = ListBox2.ListIndex + 1
        yay = Label8.Caption
        fMenu.TextBox4 = ws.Range("T" & yay + 27)
        fMenu.TextBox6 = ws.Range("W" & yay + 27)
        End Sub

        Private Sub ListBox3_Click()
        Dim say As Long, a As Byte
        Set ws = Sheets("VIP")
        Label9 = ListBox3.ListIndex + 1
        yay = Label9.Caption
        fMenu.TextBox4 = Format(ws.Range("AC" & yay + 27), "0.00000000")
        fMenu.TextBox6 = Format(ws.Range("AF" & yay + 27), "0.00000000")
End Sub
```

.....

Comment: what error you get and where...? Is it in UserForm code behind?

Comment: Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)
could not find the specified object.

Comment: Your code should be in the `UserForm code behind`. If it is not then add reference to userform like this `UserFormName.Controls(...) = ...`.

Comment: yes here. I add above

Comment: Code works for me.  Do you have controls named `Image1` to `Image20` on your form?

Comment: yes... not work for me